# Connect to Microsoft Teams Module Without Account Sign In

Tags: powershell, automation, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create an automation using

`Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $cred`.

Running it locally it prompts for a sign in window. However, when running it on another server I get the below error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Features.WinFormsLegacyWebUi.WebUI.<AcquireAuthorizationAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
```

How do I suppress the Microsoft sign in since im already passing the credentials below

```
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
 -ArgumentList $User, ($Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $Key)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the variable you're passing with the credentials is populated with data?

Comment: Does the account have MFA on? If so that would block you. It's probably better to switch to a non-user-account based login, like App credentials or certificate. See for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps#example-5-connect-to-microsoftteams-using-application-based-access-tokens

Comment: Could you please try to create $cred like below:

$user = "admin@domain.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($user, $password)
import-module microsoftteams
connect-microsoftteams -Credential $cred

Comment: @Eggnog - Have you try to create credentials like above?